# echo max value got by sql array

Tags: php

I got following array

```
Array (
    [G_ID] => 11
    [Username] => student
    [Password] => admin
    [gender] => m
    [email] => dsfsdas
    [phone] => hgjhg
    [address] => surat
    [birthdate] => 
    [interest] => 
    [goal] => 
    [User_Type] => student
    [Conform] => 1
    [l_name] => student
    [f_name] => student
    [clg_name] => scatt
    [branch] => cseq
    [avatar] => 11avatarJaguar_Logo.jpg
    [Student_Master_ID] => 11
    [Staff_Master_ID_Staff_Master] => 
    [Branch] => cseq
    [Semester] => 8
    [PEN] => 090490131013
    [SPI_1] => 6.50
    [SPI_2] => 5.20
    [SPI_3] => 7.5
    [SPI_4] => 6.5
    [SPI_5] => 8.0
    [SPI_6] => 7.1
    [SPI_7] => 8.0
    [SPI_8] => 0
    [0] => 6.50
    [max(SPI_1)] => 6.50
    [1] => 8.0
    [max(SPI_2)] => 8.0
    [2] => 7.5
    [max(SPI_3)] => 7.5
    [3] => 6.5
    [max(SPI_4)] => 6.5
    [4] => 8.0
    [max(SPI_5)] => 8.0
    [5] => 7.1
    [max(SPI_6)] => 7.1
    [6] => 8.0
    [max(SPI_7)] => 8.0
    [7] => 0
    [max(SPI_8)] => 0
)
```

I want to print this `max(SPI_1)` value.  How can I print this value?

Comment: Please *please* please format your code samples so that they are easier to read...

Comment: @joh - I'm not sure your edit helps much :/

Comment: @jeroen: That's kinda what's posted here (ok, it's a `print_r` output, but still).

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Okay, I guess I'm just used to the `var_dump` output and seeing the types and values clearly listed....

Answer (score 4):

You should read up on [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
//    key     => value
// max(SPI_1) => 6.50
```

With that knowledge, you would just do:

```
echo $student["max(SPI_1)"];
```

Comment: No its not work, i got solution.. i copy this value in another array like   $spi['one'] = $student['max(SPI_1)']; and now $spi['one']; can be print.

Comment: @vishal That makes zero sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming array is stored as `$array`

```
echo $array['max(SPI_1)'];
```

Would this not work?